# How to round a double value

Tags: c#

I need to get the value of 39197.47 as 39198.00 in C#.

Comment: This looks very difficult to google..

Comment: Looks like you want `Math.Ceiling`, not `Math.Round`.

Comment: Could you provide more detail?  For example, what should 39198.47 round to?

Comment: @Adam, no, that's rounding a different value.

Comment: 39198.47 should round up to 39199 according to the original question, surely?  In which case, Math.Ceiling would by the method to use here...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Ah didn't spot that. Although I will state that it's not necessarily pertinent to answering what has been asked directly, but is pertinent to questions that can be inferred further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To round a num n to 0 decimal places and take ceiling, use:

```
num = Math.Ceiling(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Math.Ceiling:`

```
Math.Ceiling( 39197.47 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
double x = Math.Ceiling(39197.47);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `Math.Ceiling(39197.47)` since you want to round up

Comment: Ok you are right but if give the value like this means 39197.444, the result should be 39197 only. But i'm getting 39198. so it is not the answer.

Comment: but you wanted `39198` as mentioned in the question, if you want it to be rounded below/down you can use `Math.Floor`